# Error 13 on second calculation, but not on first calculation

Tags: excel, vba

Sir,

I have written the following code for doing the calculation:

```
Sub Calculation()
    Dim i As Long, x As Long, es As Integer, lrow As Long

    lrow = Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Sheets("Data").Activate

    With Sheets("Data")
        .Range("L2:O" & lrow).ClearContents

        For x = 2 To lrow
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler01
            .Range("M" & x) = .Range("E" & x) / .Range("E" & 2)
            .Range("L" & x) = .Range("E" & x) / .Range("H" & x)
        Check01:
        Next x

        ErrorHandler01: Range("L" & x) = ""
        GoTo Check01
    End With
End Sub
```

Now this is showing `Error 13`.

The same is working with first row (with #N/A,  Row 7), but not working with the second row (i.e. row 9) values.

Require help on this.

Regards,
Swat

Comment: `Error 13` is a `Type` mismatch error. So if you remove your `On error Goto` statement (to avoid spaghetti code), what line does throw the error? Possibly: `.Range("M" & x) = .Range("E" & x) / .Range("E" & 2)` or the one after? If so, `VBA` can't devide the two values where at least one of them probably isn't a numerical value

Comment: BTW you know that you do not need VBA for this? You can use formula in `L` and `M` to achieve what you want?